# Kiosk mode in Windows 10 not working

Tags: windows-10, kiosk-mode

We're trying to implement Kiosk mode for a Classic Windows Application (WinForms) using Windows Configuration Designer from the Microsoft Store on Zebra ET5 Industry Tablet device.

I've created a provisioning package with a command line command to start the app but everytime after logon  only cmd.exe is opening. 
Even if I try notepad.exe or iexplore.exe as kiosk app it only opens cmd.exe.

We are using Windows 10 1703 Enterprise and I've followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions

There are also some errors after installing the provisioning package in the event log:

- MDM ConfigurationManager: Command failure status. Configuration Source ID: (4716416b-505b-4c21-ae16-32a994e5e831), Enrollment Name: (Provisioning), Provider Name: (Accounts), Command Type: (Add: from Replace or Add), CSP URI: (./Vendor/MSFT/Accounts/Domain/Account), Result: (Unknown Win32 Error code: 0x86000008).
- MDM ConfigurationManager: Command failure status. Configuration Source ID: (4716416b-505b-4c21-ae16-32a994e5e831), Enrollment Name: (Provisioning), Provider Name: (Provisioning), Command Type: (SetProperty: Format or Type change), CSP URI: (./Vendor/MSFT/Provisioning/ForceSettingReload/ComputerName), Result: (Unknown Win32 Error code: 0x86000011).

We have the following requirements:

- App is WinForms app available on a local path on disk C:
- App should run under domain account
- App must run in Kiosk mode

Can someone help?

Thanks
Sven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, I'd like to post the final solution.

I was able to get it working using the Windows Configuration Designer in advanced mode without the wizard. It's not working with the wizard. 
There is a feature to set your own custom shell for a certain user. This shell starts the given .exe program instead of default Windows explorer. That means you will have no task bar and no access to start menu.

We needed this for locking down tablet PCs.

The target machine must have the "Device Lockdown" Windows Feature enabled.   Otherwise you'll get only a black screen after reboot.

Good luck
Sven

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate the Shell Launcher?

Use this command:

`dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:Client-EmbeddedShellLauncher /all`

Or activate it manually. More infos here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/shell-launcher

Comment: I didn't try the command line options because we needed an easy way of creating a single package for multiple tablet PCs. It's too much overhead for each single device to run commands. I was succesful in creating a provisioning package. See my answer below.

Comment: Ah I see, wasn't aware you are just working on a single device =)